# Safety, sharing, and laziness

Tags: haskell

Is there a more succinct way to write code like this that has a lot of sharing between branches of the case statement?

(This is the main part of my solution to one of the Round 1 problems of the Facebook Hacker Cup 2012. The round is over.)

```
type Memoizable a = a -> a

recoveries :: Int -> Memoizable (String -> Int)
recoveries m = go
  where go self ('0':_) = 0
        go self [] = 1
        go self ss = flip rem 0xfaceb00c $ case analysis ss of
          HasMany
            | cValid -> cCase + bCase + aCase
            | bValid -> bCase + aCase
            | aValid -> aCase
          Has2
            | bValid -> bCase + aCase
            | aValid -> aCase
          Has1
            | aValid -> aCase
          _
            | otherwise -> 0
          where a = digitToInt (first ss)
                b = a * 10 + digitToInt (second ss)
                c = b * 10 + digitToInt (third ss)
                aValid = a <= m
                bValid = b <= m
                cValid = c <= m
                aCase = self (drop 1 ss)
                bCase = self (drop 2 ss)
                cCase = self (drop 3 ss)

-- not to be confused with functions of same name from Control.Arrow
first (x:_) = x
second (_:x:_) = x
third (_:_:x:_) = x

data Analysis = Empty | Has1 | Has2 | HasMany

-- a dumb little function to help with safety and sharing                       
analysis :: [a] -> Analysis
analysis [] = Empty
analysis [_] = Has1
analysis [_,_] = Has2
analysis _ = HasMany
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm, why did you write `go` as a separate function? It is - as you state - the same as `recoveries`, why the local definition?

For making it more succinct, I think it's easiest to have an intermediate data structure that carries both pieces of information you seek in the `case`: Whether there are enough digits and what number the digits so far would form.

The first data structure that comes to mind is a list of numbers - we just need to construct it. In this case, `scanl` is our friend:

```
import Data.List (scanl)
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

type Memoizable a = a -> a

recoveries :: Int -> Memoizable (String -> Int)
recoveries _ _    ('0':_) = 0
recoveries _ _    []      = 1
recoveries m self ss      = result `rem` 0xfaceb00c
  where result = case tail (scanl addDigit 0 ss) of
          (_:_:c:_) | c <= m  -> aCase+bCase+cCase
          (_:b:_)   | b <= m  -> aCase+bCase
          (a:_)     | a <= m  -> aCase
          _                   -> 0
        addDigit x c = x*10 + digitToInt c
        aCase = self (drop 1 ss)
        bCase = self (drop 2 ss)
        cCase = self (drop 3 ss)
```

Unless I've made a mistake (can't test), this should do the same as your code, and now we can write everything cleanly using pattern matches and a few guards on the intermediate list.

You could get rid of `aCase`, `bCase` and `cCase` as well if you would `zip` the result of `scanl` with `tails ss`. But while this is more general, I felt it would have made the code harder to understand, so I left it like this.